# Not able to receive WM_NOTIFY in HwndHost derived class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, mfc

I have an MFC application, but in some places we use WPF.  In one case I am working on, we have a WPF Window shown modally, but we are trying to display an MFC based specialized edit control inside the WPF window.

I tried to follow the cookbook and derived my class from HwndHost.  I am trying to intercept the WM_NOTIFY message of the control because it sends something like a EN_CHANGED notification through WM_NOTIFY.

I have done two things to try and intercept the method.

1) Override WndProc:

```
protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
 handled = false;

 switch (msg)
 {
    case WM_COMMAND:
       break;
    case WM_NOTIFY:
       ++NOtifyCount;
       break;
 }

 return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

2) Tap into the MessageHook event of HwndHost and have a hook procedure like this:

```
IntPtr SyntaxEditHost_MessageHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
 handled = false;

 switch (msg)
 {
    case WM_COMMAND:
       break;
    case WM_NOTIFY:
       ++NOtifyCount;
       break;
 }

 return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in either WM_NOTIFY handler, it never gets hit.  If I set a breakpoint inside the C++ code before WM_NOTIFY is sent and then set a breakpoint in the above two methods looking for ANY message, no message is received.

If I look at WM_NOTIFY messages in Spy++, I can verify that the HwndHost is receiving the messages.  Everytime I press a key in the editor, the WM_NOTIFY message is received by the HwndHost.  However, somehow the WM_NOTIFY messages are getting handled before I get a chance to handle them myself in my override of WndProc or my implementation of the message hook.

Anybody have any ideas?  Of course I googled for it and got nothing useful at all.

Comment: And for what it's worth, the HwndHost cannot receive WM_COMMAND, WM_USER, or WM_APP messages either using the above two methods.